# How to add a button to PhotoSwipe?

Tags: javascript, ipad, button, photoswipe

I made a  jAlbum PhotoSwipe skin based on the Javascript PhotoSwipe gallery, (see: http://jalbum.net/nl/skins/skin/PhotoSwipe and an adapted sample album: http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PSB/ )

I like to add an extra button to Show or Hide the Exif data of the photo.

First I tried to add a standard button in the upper right corner as advised by Dmitry Semenov, see https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/802
Although I have no idea how to add a button to the sprite default-skin.png and to default-skin.svg, you see an extra button with the same image as the 'Full screen' icon in the upper right corner on a PC with Windows 10, see http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PSB/#&gid=1&pid=5 On a touch screen device like the iPad, this'Full screen' icon is now also displayed (absent without this modification). Click on that button on a PC and on an iPad and you see that the Exif data will appear and disappear is you click that button again. So this works correct, but it is difficult to change the image.

Next I tried to add a button in the usual way with a exif.png imjage. I did add in the <div class="pswp__top-bar"> the next line:

```
<img src="res/exif.png" class="button--exif" alt="Show/Hide Exif data" title="button--exif, OK on PC not OK on iPad" onClick="javascript:toggleExif()">
```

and added to my css file:

```
 .button--exif {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

You see the result in the upper left corner of page http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PSB/#&gid=1&pid=5 
This button is visible and works on my PC. On my iPad you see the button, but the click function does not work on this touch screen device.

Finally I added did add in the <div class="pswp__top-bar"> the next line:

```
<button class="pswp__button pswp__button--play" title=".pswp__button--play, OK on PC not OK on iPad" onClick="javascript:toggleExif()"></button>
```

and added to my css file:

```
 .pswp__button--play {background-position: -188px -44px; }

 .pswp__button.pswp__button--play {
   background-image: url(play.png);
   background-size: 30px 30px;
   background-position: 0; /* or: center center; */
 }
```

You see the result as the pause button in the upper right corner of page http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PSB/#&gid=1&pid=5 
And like above, this button is visible and works on my PC. On my iPad you see the button, but the click function does not work on this touch screen device.

So my question is, what you I add / change so that my exif.png button works also on a touch screen device?

Answer (score 1):

I found the next solution to add an extra button with an image defined in a png file:

Add in the top-bar section behind pswp__counter the link and the button:

```
 <div class="pswp__counter"></div>
 <a href="javascript:toggleExif()" id="link--play"><img src="res/play.png"  width="30" height="30" id="$playpause" title="link--play, OK on PC and on iPad "></a>
```

and add to the css file:

```
#link--play  {
    position: absolute;
    right: 18%;
    padding: 6px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The z-index property is required for an iPad, but not for an Android tablet and also not for a Windows PC. You see the result as the Play buttun, left of the pause button on page http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PSB/#&gid=1&pid=5

I use this button to start a Slide Show presentation as you can see in the jAlbum PhotsSwipe skin sample album:  http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PS/